# python jupyter ipynb vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Run .ipynb with vscode, I got a error like "Timed out waiting to get a heartbeat from kernel process."
[image]

Timed out waiting to get a heartbeat from kernel process.

Does anyone have this problem? Help me please

Comment: Did you just open the .ipynb? Can you provide more details?

Comment: Yep, just open the .ipynb with vscode

Comment: It will connect to IPython kernel automatically, and few seconds later, it will report the error

Comment: Try running `pip install pypiwin32` in the terminal See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13807

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was to `conda install ipykernel` explicitly

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and struggled to find out what could be the problem. Before trying to change any settings or installing `ipykernel`, try the below steps:

1. Uninstall Python extension from VSCode
2. Uninstall Jupyter extension from VSCode
3. Restart VSCode
4. Reinstall Python and Jupyter Try it again and it should work

I have:

1. *Python extension v2021.1.502429796*
2. *Jupyter extension v2020.12.414227025*

Comment: Finally I found the answer!!! It really works reinstalling. I couldn't find this advice anywhere despite being the first thing one should have done! TYSM :)

Answer (score 2):

Update python expansion in your vscode with v2020.8.108011 version, not the 2020.9.111407 vision. Then I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For me uninstalling ipykernel and then reinstalling it, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the picture, you will see 'Busy' in the top right corner of the screen.
To resolve the ipykernel issue click on Busy and select the right option for your local machine most probably it will be Python 3.7.1 32 bit ('venv':env) Idle

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, this is because the DLL of pywin32 cannot be found, copy the pywin32 dll to C:/windows/system32, it will be all right, thanks for any help.

Comment: Please know that you can [edit] your posts. No need to create a new almost identical post. Please delete the version you like less.